# Using Sinatra with Let's Encrypt

Tags: ruby, ssl, sinatra, lets-encrypt

I plan to write a web application using the Sinatra framework, and want to add HTTPS to it using Let's Encrypt. `certbot`, the recommended Let's Encrypt client, doesn't support Sinatra, and from Googling I can't find any others which appear to support it.

Are there any Let's Encrypt clients which support Sinatra, and if not, how can I fetch a certificate from Let's Encrypt and configure Sinatra to use it? The application will be running on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinatra is merely the framework you use to build a web app on top of a web server. The only thing that matters when using a Let's Encrypt client is that you're using a supported web server such as Apache or Nginx.

The documentation lists out these requirements: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/intro.html#system-requirements

You can use `certbot` regardless of the web framework you choose as long as you're running on a supported web server.

Comment: OK, thanks - can you recommend a tutorial of setting up Apache/Nginx with Sinatra?

Comment: check out Sinatra Recipes: http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/deployment/nginx_proxied_to_unicorn

Comment: Thanks for that link.

Comment: maybe you can take a look at new nginx unit https://unit.nginx.org/ which supports ruby as well and for the ssl itself you can use nginx which plays with letsencrypt pretty well.